# Grant user access denied in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have connected to server with my workbench , and see all databases on it , but i cant see its tables.

```
could not be fetched
```

hence i have logged in mysql server by root user and create a new user in user table in mysql database , after granting access to this user i get following error :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

how can solve this problem?

this is my root user informations :

Host: 127.0.0.1

```
          User: root
          Password: 
          Select_priv: Y
          Insert_priv: Y
          Update_priv: Y
          Delete_priv: Y
          Create_priv: Y
            Drop_priv: Y
          Reload_priv: Y
        Shutdown_priv: Y
         Process_priv: Y
            File_priv: Y
           Grant_priv: Y
      References_priv: Y
           Index_priv: Y
           Alter_priv: Y
         Show_db_priv: Y
           Super_priv: Y
Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
     Lock_tables_priv: Y
         Execute_priv: Y
      Repl_slave_priv: Y
     Repl_client_priv: Y
     Create_view_priv: Y
       Show_view_priv: Y
  Create_routine_priv: Y
   Alter_routine_priv: Y
     Create_user_priv: Y
           Event_priv: Y
         Trigger_priv: Y
             ssl_type: 
           ssl_cipher: 
          x509_issuer: 
         x509_subject: 
        max_questions: 0
          max_updates: 0
      max_connections: 0
 max_user_connections: 0
```

Comment: make sure your user name and password is correct in your connection object.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to grant that user to perform actions , Please use below query :

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Of the time this error occurs due to connection problem where either user name or password went wrong in the connection object and we starts assuming that we don`t have enough privileges, so first of all please make sure that your connection objects has valid user name and password